# limit number of results displayed in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, do-while

I have an array which I loop through using a foreach statement only I only want to display the first 5 results. Here is the initial foreach statement:

```
<?php    
foreach ( $scorersCount as $player => $goals) {

$playerinfo = get_userdata($player);
$playerteam = get_user_meta($player, 'team-meta');
$teamname = get_post($playerteam[0]);
$playername = $playerinfo->user_login;

?>
<tr>
       <td class="playername"><?php echo $playername ?></td>

       <td class="teamname"><?php echo $teamname->post_title ?></td>

       <td><?php echo $goals ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php } > //end foreach
```

I presume I need to include a while statement or a do while stement within the foreach with `$i <= 5` but when I tried to do that I just got got the first result 5 times rather than the first 5 results. Can someone please show me how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `break` the `foreach` loop at your desired condition like

```
<?php  $index=0;   
foreach ( $scorersCount as $player => $goals) {

$playerinfo = get_userdata($player);
$playerteam = get_user_meta($player, 'team-meta');
$teamname = get_post($playerteam[0]);
$playername = $playerinfo->user_login;

?>
<tr>
       <td class="playername"><?php echo $playername ?></td>

       <td class="teamname"><?php echo $teamname->post_title ?></td>

       <td><?php echo $goals ?></td>
    </tr>

<?php $index++;
 if($index=== 5) {
        break;    
    }
 } ?>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I went with the earlier one as all I had to do was change my while to an if. Is there any particular reason that it is better to use a `break`or is it just personal preference.?

Comment: In my case loop will run only 5 times but in the @vulkoingim answers  case you loop will print the 5 time but run for each array value lets say if array has 100 values then loop runs 100 times but in my case loop will run 5 times you can see the performance difference

Answer (score 0):

You could also use array_chunk

```
$scorersCount = array_chunk($scorersCount,5,true);
foreach ( $scorersCount[0] as $player => $goals) {
```